# Averaging daily values from .nc file with Python

Tags: qgis, python, netcdf

I got several .nc-files from different climate models of Switzerland. Those files contain the precipitation values for each day, starting at 1981 until 2099.

The precipitation is stored like this

```
float32 pr(time, lat, lon)
```

With dimensions:

```
current shape = (43464, 101, 220)
```

Now my goal is to get a monthly precipitation value from those daily values for each lat and lon in the .nc file!

Can anyone give me an idea on how to start? I am able to print out the precipitation value for each time, lat and lon - but I am not aware how to handle such multi-dimensional arrays.

Right now I got this:

In:

```
path = '/MPICSC/CH2018_pr_MPICSC-REMO2_MPIESM_EUR11_RCP26_QMgrid_1981-2099.nc'
ds = nc.Dataset(path,'r')
rainfall = ds.variables['pr']
print (rainfall[10000,27,47])
```

Out:

```
1.984897
```

The output must be an .nc-file as well, so I can display it in QGIS

Comment: I think the tags are wrong. Here you are using the netCDF4 library in Python, the output could be loaded into any software (QGIS, ArcGIS, panoply, etc). Have you tried using xarray or rioxaarray?

Comment: I am pretty new to GIS in general. Can this averaging be done in QGIS for example?

Comment: I think you'll struggle with monthly means. Xarray (or R) is the best approach for this. If you share some example files we can guide you